# Labeling axes with non uniform ticks in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph that is plotted against two axes.  The x-axis is increasing, while the y-axis may decrease and then increase again, or it may increase the whole time, or it may decrease the whole time. It all depends on the input to the program.

### This question ONLY concerns the non-uniform y-axis.

This is for an implot (image plot) with a color bar.

I'm trying to set the tick labels in with exact set of numbers, and in the exact order that I specify, however pyplot keeps reordering my numbers in increasing value.

If I use set_ticks just by itself, it orders my ticks in increasing order, which then places them in the wrong place on my plot.

I've tried just simply using set_ticklabels and giving it my array of numbers which are already in order, and they get displayed properly, but my ticks are getting cut off of the plot in some way and lining up poorly, no matter what nbin param I give to the MaxNLocator I'm using.

If anyone has experience with this, help would be much appreciated.

thanks!

## minimal example

```
100
80
70         .      .
60 
70    .
80              .
90
-----------------------------
```

Possible tick labels for y-axis:

```
[1,10,30,40,50,60,40,30,20,1]
[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
[10,9,4,3,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]
```

I need these lists of tick labels to be plotted AS-IS, with index 0 corresponding to the bottom of the Y-axis, not reordered in increasing or decreasing order, and with no interpolation between numbers in any way, which is what pyplot seems to like to do, screwing up readability of my plot.

### Code I'm using

```
# Code for setting up figure, extent, etc.
# ....
# ....
fig5ax.yaxis.set_ticks(rangeLabelSet)
fig5ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(rangeLabelSet)
yloc = pyplot.MaxNLocator(nbins=len(rangeLabelSet), prune=None, trim=False, symmetric=False)
```

Comment: Provide minimal example please

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for the response. Edited question, let me know if you need more

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to change the labels, not the values of the y-axis that they correspond to, right?

Comment: Nevermind, just realized you are trying to do `set_ticks` as well.

Comment: This is for an image plot with a colorbar, so the y-axis values are estimated via the range of the values anyways - so, yes, just the labels

Comment: Would you be OK with having a monotonically increasing axis, but with labels that were not monotonically increasing?

Comment: If just the labels, the easiest way is probably `fig5ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels([str(x) for x in rangeLabelSet])`. The values won't be messed with if they are strings.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't honestly know what I should be doing. (if I even need set_ticks) .. I just need the labels that I specify to be evenly spaced across the Y-axis, in the order I specify.  This is for an image plot with a colorbar, so the y-axis values are estimated via the range of the values anyways - so, yes, just the labels

Comment: @MadPhysicist Is that different then `fig5ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(rangeLabelSet)` ?? I've tried this and It refuses to line up well. I think I'm using the wrong locator or something

Comment: If your tick **labels** are `[1,10,30,40,50,60,40,30,20,1]`, what are the **actual** y-values? Are they just integers up to the size of the image?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The graph has an x and y axis, where the value in each cell [x,y] in the image plot is a function of x and y and is labeled by a color.  The pyplot.implot just plots the matrix and I'm trying to label the axes according to the progression of Y along the matrix.  The values of x and y and their progressions are dynamic via user input.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Those are the actual y-values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117142/discussion-between-mad-physicist-and-riptyde4).

Comment: I posted a thing in chat.